# ArcObjects (VB.Net) Python Integration with object passing?

Tags: python, arcobjects

This [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000m0s000000) illustrates one method for calling python scripts from within an ArcObjects environment.  The results of these tasks are returned as strings.  I wonder if it is possible to call a python script and pass objects back and forth.

For example, assume I have defined a 2-dimensional array (in VB.Net) of x,y coordinate pairs.  I want to pass this object to a .py script that will perform some computation (doesn't matter what really) and return a dictionary of lists, i.e. `{"1":[2,3,4], "2":[1,3,4], "8":[9,11,5]}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to pass objects between .net and python, but you can use a common data structure like JSON to pass data in string form back and forth and restructure using something like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) which has a method of deserializing the raw JSON string into a dictionary.  It should be easy to find a library that does this on the python end as well.  [Here's a usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1212115/1337783).